# Why "add comment", not an "add a comment" in Area 51 example questions section?

Tags: bug, comments, area-51

There is an **add comment** in each question of the Area 51 proposal's **Example Questions** sections to enter the comment about the question, but in the tool tip of an add comment and in the discussion zone's question and answer sections are also it is showing as **add a comment**.

For the consistency over the site, it should be **add a comment** in the example questions section.

*Even it is **add a comment** in the other Stack Exchange communities*

Screen shot from the example questions section with tool tip:

[image: Add comment but tool tip is add a comment]

Comment: Probably because they aren't working on Area 51 any more. Regardless, there's nothing wrong with omitted articles in some places.

Comment: Just one of many quirks of Area 51. IIRC it's on an older SE code base than the rest of the sites.